# Best software for taking a "System Information Snapshot"?

Tags: network-monitoring

I am curious what people would recommend as the best software for taking a system information snapshot?   This would be for use in a technical support fashion.

Comment: Windows or UNIX?

Comment: "This would be for use in a technical support fashion." That sentence tells us absolutely nothing, could you please elaborate? Do you mean tech support being provided to end users, and you have remote techs working with them? Software like LogMeInRescue do a good job of detailing the system for a remote tech.

Do you mean for servers that your L1 and L2 teams have to support? Backups and a well-maintained CMDB are your ticket there, along with good documentation for business applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually write my own in Perl. The Perl program is fairly simple: run programs (or print files) found in a configuration file, and output results with headers.

This program then runs things like `df -h`, `lvdisplay -v`, `vgdisplay -v`, `uname -a`, and so on. I also print files like /etc/nsswitch.conf, and usually add a way to create custom headers.  Build up as desired.